# Angular2 one way databinding in input field

Tags: angular, typescript, input, data-binding

Very simple, I have a component containing a string

I need to show this string in an input field.

I thought I need it like this but it doesn't work.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <input type="text" ([ngModel])="myVar" >
    `
})

export class MyComponent{

  constructor(){
  } 

  myVar: string = "Hello World"

}
```

Comment: Use `[(ngModel)]="myVar"` (or `[ngModel]="myVar"` if it is just 1-way binding)

Comment: True your ngModel syntax is wrong

Comment: `[ngModel]="myVar"` doesn't work

Comment: @ttmt you don't need `name` attribute unless you use this input as a template driven formControl (not mentioned in the original OP). For implementing the binding between the `input` field and the component property just the right 'banana-in-a-box' syntax should suffice. See [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#two-way-data-binding-in-a-nutshell) to learn more on implementing 2-way bindings. Also, like I mentioned, `[ngModel]` is just 1-way binding - meaning it will populate the value once from the component to the view on initial load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is :

`([ngModel])="myVar"` => `[(ngModel)]="myVar"`

add name field in input type **name="myVar"**

Try Like this :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-compoent.template.html';
})
export class MyComponent {
    myVar: string = "Hello World"
    constructor() { }
}
```

in html you need to add name in input type

```
<input type="text" name="myVar" [(ngModel)]="myVar" >
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the name I was missing.

Comment: Name shouldn't have anything to do with this, it was the order of parans for the two-way data-binding that fixed it.

Comment: That was a typo sorry, it was the name that fixed it for me.

Comment: Isn't this 2 way binding?

Answer (score 3):

`([ngModel])` syntax is wrong, it should be `[(ngModel)]`. Notice the order of parans.

Mnemonic is **banana in the box**. `[` looks like a box and `(` looks like a banana.

---

Also you seem to have a typo in the path to your template file, it says `./my-compoent` instead of `./my-component` which is what the file is probably named.